# How to import Stanford CoreNLP library to Android Studio

Tags: android, stanford-nlp

How can i add Stanford Core Natural Language Processes library into Android Studio project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it from **maven repository** - [Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.9.1)

Or just import by adding this app level build.gradle

```
compile "edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.9.1"
```

In my honest opinion I **wouldn't recommend** to use it android as its **too heavy**

On Github they also have suggested to use dedicated back end **server** to utilize its functionality - [Github Issue](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/623#issuecomment-364255895)