# How to check if any date is present in String Dart

Tags: string, flutter, date, dart

I have a string and I have to check if it contains any date like for example 22/03/2021.
I dont want to match the exact date I just need to check if any date is present.
Exact code will help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this.

There's a class called [`DateFormat`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) which contains various date/time formats, but I couldn't find any regexes in it. If you want to follow this lead, then you might want to create a list of regexes yourself (there's a bunch [in here](https://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)) and evaluate each and every one until you find a match.

The only other thing that comes to my mind is processing the string with NLP. You have a couple choices there, you could utilize Firebase, create a native plugin with [`Apache NLP`](https://opennlp.apache.org/), [`Stanford CoreNLP`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436326/how-to-import-stanford-corenlp-library-to-android-studio) or create a tiny REST backend yourself.

It won't be perfect, but maybe that's good enough for you. (visit https://corenlp.run/ for an online example)

```
My birthday party is going to be held on 22/03/2021. 
It will start at 12:30. 
I'm also going hiking next monday. 
It will be 23 Feb.
```

[image]

Edit. As you can see it doesn't recognize `22/03/2021` but it works with US format fine: `2021/03/22`. I assume it depends on locale/language used.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RegExp to see if there's a date pattern inside the string, capture it and to wharever you need.

```
RegExp exp = new RegExp('\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}');
String str = "test string 01/06/1986 with a date inside";
String match = exp.firstMatch(str)?.group(0);
```

You could do `allMatches` to get all dates pattern on the string.